# htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess

My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

`RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$

RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.cc$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.cc/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When my website is accessed using the `domain.co.cc/` URL it loads. When it is accessed using the `www.domain.co.cc` URL it does not.

The last two lines of my `.htaccess` file should redirect users from `www.domain.co.cc` to the correct `domain.co.cc`, but it is not working correctly.

Could some help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need rewrite rules for the domain name.  This is a DNS level problem, not a problem with the http configuration.  You need to check there is an A record for www.domain.co.cc points to the same address as the A record for domain.co.cc

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you enter www.domain.co.cc?

Maybe the DNS A-record for www is set to a wrong IP-Address?